# Three knights on a 3x3 chess board

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

[image]

There are two white knights (W) and black nights(B) positioned at a 3x3 chess board. Find them minimum number of moves required to replace the black  knights with the whites.Any type of move is allowed not necessarily alternating black and white.No capturing is allowed white or black knights can not  move to block which is already filled with any other knight(black or white). The position at which the whites knights  were before is to be replaced by the black knights similarly white knights are to be placed where black knights were initially .I  tried to do this  but not able to finally find a answer. I am confused.

Comment: You can do it in sixteen moves, just let them move around in a circle! I would even say that this is the minimum number of moves (if it is not allowed for two knights to occupy the same field at the same time).

Comment: @Achal: Can u tell , if the rules are the same as  standard chess, example if the white knight is in the capturing zone of black knight then can black knight  capture the white knight ?

Comment: I have to ask the same as @RK. And I would like further clarification. Are you able to move _any_ piece, black or white, or do they have to be moved in the usual chess pattern of turns? If turns are not followed, and one may replace the black knights, then just move the white knights to the middle, then replace the black knights with them. That is 4 moves and is the absolute minimum you can have.

Comment: No, we just have to replace the positions but two knights cant  be at  the same position and no turns are to be followed any one can be moved.

Comment: Please elaborate. What sort of moves are allowed? Alternating black and white, or any moves? Captures? What do you mean by "replace"? Should they swap places, or is the black knight "replaced" by a white knight as soon as the white knight takes its place?

Comment: If you can capture them to "replace" them, this is trivial. So presumably it asks about having them switch places entirely.

Comment: An observation that might be of use: the middle square is redundant. It can never be reached.

Comment: Where did you get this puzzle from?

Comment: Three knights in the title, four knights in the body. What's up with that?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: ‘Untwist’ the board by converting this:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\color{blue}0&3&\color{brown}6\\ \hline
5&&1\\ \hline
\color{blue}2&7&\color{brown}4\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

to this:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\color{blue}0&1&\color{blue}2\\ \hline
7&&3\\ \hline
\color{brown}6&5&\color{brown}4\\ \hline
\end{array}$$