# Knight shift on $3×3$ chess board

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

The chess table has $2$ Black and $2$ White knights marked with $C =$ $Black$ and $B =$ $White$.  Is it possible to move the pieces from their initial position to get the positions on $2$?

Comment: Why would you use **B** for *white*, not *black*?

Comment: It's in Serbian and B is short for Bijela which means white :v

Comment: This is a different question, but closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366435/three-knights-on-a-3x3-chess-board

Comment: I solved it using graph theory, can I post my answer? I know it's my own question but I figured it out in the mean time.

Comment: Sure!  By all means, post!

Answer (score 3):

The knight's moves form a cycle graph on the $3\times 3$ board shown. The knights shown are in fixed order around that cycle and cannot be reordered to produce the desired formation without having two pieces occupy the same square, which I'm assuming is forbidden.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Representing the problem as a circle gives the picture below. The positions on the bord which are marked from 1 to 9 are vertices of the given graph and the edges represent the legal moves a knight can do. As one can see from the rather poor illustration moving any of the knights clockwise or counter-clockwise just brings us back to the initial positions of having two black on one side and two white on the other, so I conclude that it is impossible to move them to that position in the second picture.

Comment: Even though I too believe it is impossible to make the target transformation, I don't find this answer compelling as a "proof."  Isn't there some what using parity or other mathematical constraint to prove that no such transformation is possible?